# My 'show items with no data' option is greyed out in Field settings

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to set my pivot table to show no data items, I normally  click on 'show items with no data' in field settings however this option is greyed out for me. I have also tried using 'show items with no data on rows/ columns' in pivot table options but this has also not worked for me. After spending hours trying to find an answer through google I'm still non the wiser.

As per your request please see screen shoot of the selection I am trying to make.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide any examples? Perhaps posting a screenshot of your sheet would help. This gives any potential helpers more information and allows them to work with data that matches yours.

Comment: Hi I have just added a picture of the selection I am trying to make